# Cross Origin Frame Error in a visualforce page using Lightning Out

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-out

I have a lightning component which uses external libraries like d3.js and jquery.
I have to use this this component in a lightning page as well as show it on the record detail page of a custom object. I am doing this by using adding the component in an app which is then added to the visualforce page by Lightning Out. 
Some Observations are:

1. Opening the visualforce using the classic url (/apex/mypage) works fine.
2. In the record detail page, it throws a cross origin frame error.
3. If I remove the `ltng:require` from the component and remove the loading of the d3 and jquery static resource, it works in the detail page (but does not render charts and stuff obviously unless I import it in the vf page(but I need it run independently as well)).

How do I fix this error or render the lightning component in the record detail page through lightning out.

Sample Code: https://jsfiddle.net/2rf4qq6t/

Comment: Please share your component code and your visualforce code

Comment: check the jsfiddle link

Comment: there is no lightning component in this jsfiddle...

Comment: cant write the entire component because of the size and complexity as well as copyright I assume, but the basic markup has been added. The component works fine independently

Comment: You can add code here, if not all - at least the main parts. Sorry, cannot help without code...